# Reading a file using Apache Camel from an FTP location

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-cdi

I have a requirement to read a file continuously from an FTP location and write to some topic(for eg:Kafka) using Apache Camel. I am able to read the file in the startup and write to the topic. Is there a way in Camel to read the file continuously from a folder whenever a new file come in to that location?

Comment: Can you share with us how your ftp endpoint looks like

Comment: Is it a new file with a different name, or is the old file appended with new data, or what? But yeah sure the FTP component can keep reading new files/changed files etc. See the idempotent / readLock options.

Comment: It worked after using idempotent option